# ImageResizer Can't apply Preset in Rewrite Event (Presets already expanded)

Tags: c#, asp.net, imageresizer

I have a need to be able to analyse the requested image URL and apply resize commands based on the URL requested without the user seeing the resize commands in the url. E.g.

`http://someurl.com/image/category/image-title.jpg`

To do this I have hooked into Pipeline_Rewrite - basic example below:

```
    void Pipeline_Rewrite(IHttpModule sender, HttpContext context, ImageResizer.Configuration.IUrlEventArgs e)
    {
        // Clear the current command string - we're going to create a new one
        e.QueryString.Clear();

        var process = ((Global)HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance).ContainerProvider.RequestLifetime.Resolve<Interfaces.IRequestBuilder>();
        // Set the "new" command string
        e.QueryString = process.BuildCommandList(context);            
    }
```

`BuildCommandList(context)` analyses the current url and constructs a list of appropriate commands to add to the querystring, and returns a `NameValueCollection`. This all works fine, and the commands are applied, unless the new commands are a `Preset` defined in the config.

E.g.

If `BuildCommandList(context)` returns the equivalent of `width=150&height=150`, this works.

If `BuildCommandList(context)`  returns the equivalent of `preset=thumbnail` this doesn't work, I just get the full size original image.

On further investigation, it looks like any Preset commands have already been expanded to their relevant command strings before the `Pipeline_Rewrite` method runs, so adding them here is too late.

Extract from the web.config file:

```
<resizer>
   <presets onlyAllowPresets="false">
      <preset name="thumbnail" settings="width=150;height=150" />
   </presets>
   <plugins>
      <add name="Presets" />
   </plugins>
</resizer>
```

Is there any way to clear the command string, apply a preset, and have ImageResizer reprocess the presets at this point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want Presets to work with your event handler, your event handler needs to be registered first.

I would suggest removing `<add name="Presets" />` from web.config, and instead installing it after you register your event handler, via `new ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.Presets().Install(Config.Current);`

Comment: Adding `new ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.Presets().Install(Config.Current);` directly below the line where I registered my event handler in `Application_Start` sorted the problem.